# Safari & Chrome: Javascript - window.showModal Dialog Text Box issue.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

i have using window.showmodalDialog for opening the modal window. In this winodow, i have some issues in  CrossBrowsers:

1) window.showmodaldialog Modal window not works like IE, which means it works like window.open.

this issue in Chrome and Safari

2) if i use TAB key to move next textbox it automatically Positioned into Middle of the Text box and also clears the values in the text box.

this issue only in safari.

Need solution:

Any alternate way for Window.ShowModalDialog() for all the browsers.

window.showModalDialog('/servlet/ZServlet?api=loadJDetails&job=1&dflag=0&dEditFlag=0&rand='+myRandom,obj,"dialogHeight: 600px; dialogWidth: 1100px; dialogTop: px; dialogLeft: px; center: Yes; help: No; resizable: No; status: No; scroll: yes;");

[image: Cursor postion after using tab key]

Code for calling Modal Window:

Any Help ?